# Intermittent 401-Unauthorized response from SSRS

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, reporting-services, windows-security

*(using C#, Web API, SQL Server2012 w/report server, authentication is NTLM)*

I am getting an intermittent error when attempting to download a report (as an excel document) from SSRS. I build out the correct URL to render the report like:

> http://sqlServer/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?/TheReportName&rs:Command=Render&rs:format=excel&rc:Parameters=false&Region=WEST&CutOffDate=10/25/2015

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myDom\\myReportReader", "P@55W0rd");
     //string credentials = Convert.ToBase64String(
     //    Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("myDom\\myReportReader" + ":" + P@55W0rd"));
     //webClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = string.Format("Basic {0}", credentials);

//401 Unauthorized thrown here:
return new MemoryStream(webClient.DownloadData(reportUrl));
```

The goal here is that a Web API controller on public facing IIS downloads the filestream from an internal/firewall protected SSRS and then relays the stream to browser.
This WORKS sometimes...when it doesn't it returns a 401 error on the last line...
The remarked out line represent an attempt to resolve the problem which did not work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**One solution** is to change the requested URL.

SSRS responds by redirect (http status 302), when you want to export a report through ReportViewer.aspx. And WebClient does not resend the credentials to the redirected page.

You should request the report in this format:
http://sqlServer/ReportServer?/TheReportName&rs:Format=EXCEL&rc:Parameters...
so simply delete from URL this sequence: **/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx**.

More about exporting a report using URL access is here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms154040.aspx

**Another solution** is to leave the non-optimal URL and use `CredentialCache`, it will provide the credentials to the redirected page, but don't forget to set `Uri` parameter only to the URL **prefix**, that is 'http://sqlServer' or 'http://sqlServer/ReportServer', not more.

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
var nc = new NetworkCredential("myReportReader", "P@55W0rd", "myDom");
var cc = new CredentialCache{{new Uri("http://sqlServer"), "Ntlm", nc}};
webClient.Credentials = cc;
return new MemoryStream(webClient.DownloadData(reportUrl));
```

Comment: I had actually arrived at the first solution, as a working solution. I had also tried the second approach and it did not change the results I was getting.

Comment: "delete from URL this sequence: /Pages/ReportViewer.aspx." I've been searching for hours and that fix my issue. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

you can pass the ssrs report as a parameter to the SSRS report server from powershell.   SSRS redirects to the report.  The reportname becomes a parameter to the SSRS report server.

$SSRSurl="http://reports.abc.company.com/ReportServer?/My+Directory+For++Reports/ABCReport&Field1Param=123&Field2Param=321&rs:Format=EXCEL"

```
$spreadsheet_file="abc.xls"
$Path = "C:\download_directory\$spreadsheet_file"
$WebClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$WebClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.Networkcredential($User, $PasswordAsString)
$WebClient.DownloadFile( $SSRSurl, $path )
```